# How to format output of ifconfig

Tags: linux, bash, sed

I need to transfom the result of command `ifconfig -a` to the following format

```
IFACE eth0 192.168.30.8 Ethernet
IFACE eth1 212.233.112.171 Ethernet
IFACE lo 127.0.0.1 Local Loopback 
IFACE pan0 0.0.0.0 Ethernet
IFACE tunl0 0.0.0.0 IPIP Tunnel
```

I know that I should do that with the `sed` or something similar.
For now I have the following "script":

```
ifconfig -a | sed -r -n -e 'N' -e 's/(\w+)(\s*)(Link\sencap:)(\w+(\s\w+)*)([^\n]*)\n\s+(inet\saddr:)([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3}).*/IFACE \1 \8 \4/p'
```

The original `ifconfig -a` output is (`...` means ommited parts)

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f4:ce:46:99:22:57
          inet addr:192.168.30.8  Bcast:192.168.31.255  Mask:255.255.254.0
          ...
eth1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:23:7d:fd:a2:d0
          inet addr:212.233.112.171  Bcast:212.233.112.175  Mask:255.255.255.240
          ...
lo        Link encap:Local Loopback
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          ...
pan0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr f6:d0:8a:0e:7b:95
          BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          ...
tunl0     Link encap:IPIP Tunnel  HWaddr
          NOARP  MTU:1480  Metric:1
          ...
```

**The first problem** with this transformation is that IP address resides on the second line from the interface name and type. A used the `-N` argument to concat the lines, but they are being concat in pairs, and if the name of the interface is on odd line - I have troubles: script skips the interface on the odd line, like this (NOTE that there are no mentioning about pan0 in the output.):

```
IFACE eth0 192.168.30.8 Ethernet 
IFACE eth1 212.233.112.171 Ethernet 
IFACE lo 127.0.0.1 Local Loopback
IFACE tunl0 IPIP Tunnel
```

**The second problem** is that I don't know how to insert zero-address when there are no IP adress in `ifconfig -a` output.

Comment: I think you should start with the output of `ip addr` instead. Then you need to parse that in a similar way.

Comment: `ip addr` output has the same problem - `ip address` is on the next line after device name (

Comment: Regarding the first problem, you can use `awk 'FNR==number_of_line {print}'` to choose the line number.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that `ifconfig` output varies with platforms, so this is not a very portable way of doing it.

As to a sed solution, I think you need to break the parsing into multiple steps, something like this should work (GNU sed):

*parse.sed*

```sed
s/^([^ ]+) */\1\n/                               # interface name
s/Link encap:(.*)(  |$).*/\1/                    # link encapsulation
N                                                # append next line to PS
/inet addr/! s/\n[^\n]*$/\n0.0.0.0\n/            # use 0.0.0.0 if no "inet addr"
s/ *inet addr:([^ ]+).*/\1\n/                    # capture ip address if present
s/\n[^\n]*$//                                    # cleanup the last line
s/([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)\n([^\n]+)/IFACE \1 \3 \2/p  # print entry
s/.*//                                           # empty PS
: loop                                           # \
N                                                #  \
/^\n$/b                                          #   skip until next empty line
s/.*//                                           #  /
b loop                                           # /
```

*Explanation*

The idea is to capture all the relevant information in pattern space with newline delimiters.

*Testing*

Run like this:

```
ifconfig -a | sed -rf parse.sed
```

Output:

```
IFACE eth0 192.168.30.8 Ethernet
IFACE eth1 212.233.112.171 Ethernet
IFACE lo 127.0.0.1 Local Loopback
IFACE pan0 0.0.0.0 Ethernet
IFACE tunl0 IPIP Tunnel
```

Comment: WOW! one question, the 0.0.0.0 is substituted by the detecting words "BROADCAST MULTICAST", am I right? Is it possible to change this behavior to insert 0.0.0.0 if `inet addr:` wasn't set explicitly?

Comment: @AntonBoritskiy: that simplifies things a bit, see the updated version

Comment: I would like to see the Thor vs steve :)

Answer (score 3):

I've already accepted the Thor's answer, but here is my solution, which is a bit different. I was thinking it over while waiting for an answer.

```
ip addr | sed -r ':a;N;$!ba;s/\n\s/ /g' | sed -r -n -e 's/^([0-9]+):\s(\w+).*(link\/(\w+))\s[a-f0-9:.]{,17}\sbrd\s[a-f0-9:.]{,17}\s*(inet\s([0-9]{1,3}(\.[0-9]{1,3}){3})).*/IFACE \2 \6 \4/p' -e 's/^([0-9]+):\s(\w+).*(link\/(\w+))\s[a-f0-9:.]{,17}\sbrd\s[a-f0-9:.]{,17}.*/IFACE \2 0.0.0.0 \4/p'
```

output:

```
IFACE lo 127.0.0.1 loopback
IFACE eth0 192.168.30.8 ether
IFACE eth1 212.233.112.171 ether
IFACE pan0 0.0.0.0 ether
IFACE tunl0 0.0.0.0 ipip
```

the main advantage - it can be called as is. The second advantage is that the ordering of interfaces coinsides with interface indexes (I got this when started comparing results of `ifconfig` and `ip addr`).

But Thorn's solution is much more readable and maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

I got something!

```
ifconfig -a | tr -s ' ' | awk -F'[: ]' '
  {if (/^[a-z]/) printf "IFACE " $1 " " $4}
  {if (/inet addr:/) print " " $4}'
```

Explanation:

- `tr -s ' '` delete multiple spaces.
- `-F'[: ]'` defines multiple delimiters: `:` and  (space).
- `{if (/^[a-z]/) ...` whenever somethings begins with a letter, print field 1 and 4.
- `{if (/inet addr:/) ...` whenever somethings contains `_inet addr_`, print field $4

Output:

```
IFACE lo Local127.0.0.1
IFACE wlan0 Ethernet192.168.1.61
```

As you can see, they are not in the same order but I could not get it.

Answer (score 0):

For better readability and maintainability, you could use awk for this. Here's one way with GNU awk:

*parse.awk*

```awk
function get2(s) {
  split(s, a, ":")
  return a[2]
}

{
  link = ip = ""
  for(i=2; i<=NF; i++) {
    switch($i) {
      case /Link encap/ : link = get2($i); break
      case /inet addr/  : ip   = get2($i); break
    }
  }

  print "IFACE", $1, (ip=="")?"0.0.0.0":ip, link
}
```

Run it like this:

```
ifconfig -a | awk -f parse.awk RS='\n\n' FS=' {2,}|\n'
```

Output:

```
IFACE eth0 192.168.30.8 Ethernet
IFACE eth1 212.233.112.171 Ethernet
IFACE lo 127.0.0.1 Local Loopback
IFACE pan0 0.0.0.0 Ethernet
IFACE tunl0 0.0.0.0 IPIP Tunnel
```